# How can I render a wpf control to a DrawingContext?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Can I get a Geometry of a Visual/UIElement/FrameworkElement and use DrawingContext.DrawDrawing ?

Currently I am using a RenderTargetBitmap, draw my Visual to it and use DrawingContext.DrawImage .

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on what you are trying to achieve? I was playing around with an adorner today trying to draw a control from the OnRender method into the DrawingContext. I quit that was simply able to add the control to my Adorner's Visual and Logical tree; this made the control render itself and be completely functional.